# renaming array group name

Tags: php, arrays, rename

I want to change numbers in arrays [0], [1] etc
I don't know their names aswell to be honest but I have made arrows after them

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [0] => Array  # <----- this [0]
        (
            [prod] => 
        )

    [1] => Array # <----- this [1]
        (
            [item] => 1
            [place] => 2
            [holder] => 2
            [type] => 1
            [amount] => 1
            [sellprice] => 13000.00
            [buyprice] => 12000.00
            [notification] => 16
        )
)
```

wanted result :

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    ['Some Title'] => Array  # <----- this [0]
        (
            [prod] => 
        )

    ['Title'] => Array # <----- this [1]
        (
            [item] => 1
            [place] => 2
            [holder] => 2
            [type] => 1
            [amount] => 1
            [sellprice] => 13000.00
            [buyprice] => 12000.00
            [notification] => 16
        )
)
```

I want to replace those [0] and [1] with some titles

this code is being generated with array_push

Comment: Can you post what you want the output to look like?

Comment: hi, welcome to SO, did you take a look at PHP documentation ?https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: @bassxzero check edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array(); // your array
// your array push code goes here
    $arr['Title'] = $arr[0];
    $arr['Title 2'] = $arr[1];
    unset($arr[0]);
    unset($arr[1]);
```